# Removing nodes from xml when attribute and text content match using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am having difficulties transforming an xml. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <organisation>
        <school>
            <name>school of arts Berlin</name>
            <address>123street</address>
        </school>
    </organisation>
    <teachers>
        <wo_number>34A</wo_number>
        <publication>
            <date>14-09-2018</date>
            <name>J. doe</name>
        </publication>
        <teacher id="A254">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="A254">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="B254">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="X92">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
    </teachers>
</root>
```

What i am trying to achieve:

- teacher element has an attribute id, if it starts with "A2" AND the text content of the element ill within the same teacher node equals to "yes" the teacher node must be removed
- teacher element has an attribute id, if it starts with "G5" AND the text content of the element ill within the same teacher node equals to "probable" the teacher node must be removed

the correct outcome should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <organisation>
        <school>
            <name>school of arts Berlin</name>
            <address>123street</address>
        </school>
    </organisation>
    <teachers>
        <wo_number>34A</wo_number>
        <publication>
            <date>14-09-2018</date>
            <name>J. doe</name>
        </publication>
        <teacher id="A254">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="B254">
            <situation>
                <ill>probable</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="X92">
            <situation>
                <ill>no</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
        <teacher id="G56">
            <situation>
                <ill>yes</ill>
            </situation>
        </teacher>
    </teachers>
</root>
```

so far i haven't been able to achive this. I am stuck at the first (requirement) bullit written above. Here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!--xsl:template match="teachers"-->
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="teacher-to-remove" select="'yes'"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="teacher">
        <xsl:if test="(not(contains(concat(',', $teacher-to-remove, ','), concat(',', situation/ill, ','))) and not(starts-with(@id, 'A2')))">   
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

with this outcome:

```
    <root>
        <organisation>
            <school>
                <name>school of arts Berlin</name>
                <address>123street</address>
            </school>
        </organisation>
        <teachers>
            <wo_number>34A</wo_number>
            <publication>
                <date>14-09-2018</date>
                <name>J. doe</name>
            </publication>


            <teacher id="B254">
                <situation>
                    <ill>probable</ill>
                </situation>
            </teacher>
            <teacher id="X92">
                <situation>
                    <ill>no</ill>
                </situation>
            </teacher>
            <teacher id="G56">
                <situation>
                    <ill>probable</ill>
                </situation>
            </teacher>

        </teachers>
    </root>
```

All teacher nodes with element 
`<ill>yes</ill>` are removed which is not correct and all teacher nodes with id A254 are removed which is also not correct. the xsl:if condition isn't working the way i expected (or wanted). Some help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No need for 2.0 for this conditional node removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using two empty templates:

```
<xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id,'A2') and situation/ill='yes']" />
<xsl:template match="teacher[starts-with(@id,'G5') and situation/ill='probable']" />
```

They filter out the unwanted elements.

Comment: thank you for your answer. this works, unfortunately i made a fatal mistake a teacher node can have multiple situation elements in a teacher node. I've edited the question.my apologies. Could you take another look at my question?

Comment: This is against SO's rules. You should accept this (correct) answer and create a new question with the new conditions. Otherwise it would create chaos among the states of the current question and the current answer. That this is not desirable must be obvious. So this question should be rolled-back.

Comment: agreed, i will ask a new question.